# Sort All Results In Laravel Model By Separate Model Entity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've found a way to sort a laravel model by a seperate model's(also named model, as in model of a car) 'hits' by using the DB::table function, but I want to know how to get the same results using Eloquent only

ie (DB::table way)

```
DB::table('series')
->join('model','model.series_id','=','series.id')
->orderBy('model.hits', 'asc')
->get();
```

This returns an array of stdClass Objects, however I want to find a way to return it as an array of Model Objects, again Model referring to the model named model (sorry for confusion).

ie (if you just found one model)

```
Model::orderBy('hits', 'asc')->get();
```

but obviously I want to retrieve the series. Sorry I'm a bit new and I'm not sure how to explain it any better than this. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`Eager Load Constraints`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)?

```
Series::with(array('models' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('hits');
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DB:: will return stdObjects, but you can easily do just the same with Eloquent:

```
// Assuming your models are Serie.php and 
// Hit.php, with table hits: id, count, serie_id ...

Serie::join('hits', 'hits.serie_id', '=', 'series.id')
  ->orderBy('hits.count', 'asc')
  ->get();
```

This will return Eloquent Collection.

Eager loading won't work here, as it does not join the tables, so you would end up with ordered related Hits for each Serie, but it would not affect Series order.

However if you still need related model (Hit) for every Serie then use eager loading as well to avoid n+1 problem.